# Drawing paths in an OSM map

Tags: servlets, prolog, openstreetmap, shortest-path

In an experiment with Prolog I would like to use the data provided from [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) to calculate, for example, the shortest path to traverse a collection of points of interest. I have an idea how to do that with Prolog, and even how to access my Prolog program from a Java servlet (responsible of rendering the page with the map, or provide information to it if needed).

However, since I am new to OSM I still do not know how to let the users select a certain amount of nodes from the map, and how to answer (I mean, how to draw in the map) the shortest path to traverse them (given a user selected starting node). Could someone give me a hint about how I can ask, using an OSM map,  many points of interest from a user and later draw a path between them as an answer ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Karussell!, the short answer is that I need this for the validation of a library I have developed. The long one is that Java is great for modeling real-world concepts. Prolog is better for declarative reasoning. If your problem can easily be expressed as a set of logic rules, there is a high chance that a declarative logic language is the best choice for that problem.

Comment: Very off-topic but I don't think you should choose this "declaration stuff" on language level (I made this mistake too some years ago!). Prolog was very nice at the beginning but falls hard for bigger problems (or should I say 'falls slow' ;) ?). There are a bunch of optimization libraries which are fast&good for 'normal' languages like drools solver, coin-or project etc

Comment: hopefully on-topic: for shortest path (not traveling salesman!) I recommend my Java project GraphHopper which can read OSM (see OSMReader) ;)